# Having trouble setting cookies using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on setting cookies for a website and I've been having trouble getting it right. When I check DevTools on my browser (Chrome), I'm always getting messages about the SameSite attribute being unspecified. Would anyone be able to help out?

```
const dropCookie = true;
const cookieDays = 14;
const cookieName = "Compliance";
const cookieState = "on";
const banner = document.getElementById("cookie-banner");

const displayBanner = () => {
    const main = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];

    banner.style.display = "flex";
    main.className += " cookie-banner";

    createCookie(window.cookieName, window.cookieState, window.cookieDays);
}

const createCookie = (name, value, days) => {
    let cookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    if (typeof days === "number") {
        const date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        const expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    if (window.dropCookie) {
        cookie = `${name}=${value}; ${expires}; path=/; secure; samesite=none`
        document.cookie = cookie;
    }
}

function checkCookie(name) {
    const nameEq = `${name}=`;
    const cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (let i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++) {
        let c = cookieArr[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == " ") c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEq) == 0) return c.substring(nameEq.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}

window.onload = () => {
    if (checkCookie(window.cookieName) != window.cookieState) {
        displayBanner();
    }
}
```

Comment: Only use a cookie if you want it to expire. Most of the time you just want to use `localStorage` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there were several reference errors being thrown from my code. I had to correct the instances where I referenced variables as properties of `window`, and also fix the Unix to UTC time conversion in `createCookie`.

```
const dropCookie = true;
const cookieDays = 14;
const cookieName = "compliance";
const cookieState = "on";
const banner = document.getElementById("cookie-banner");

const displayBanner = () => {
    const main = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];

    banner.style.display = "flex";
    main.className += " cookie-banner";

    createCookie(cookieName, cookieState, cookieDays);
}

const closeBanner = () => {
    banner.style.display = "none";
}

const createCookie = (name, value, days) => {
    let cookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    if (typeof days === "number") {
        let date = new Date();
        let unixDate = date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        date = new Date(unixDate);
        const expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        if (dropCookie) {
            document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; ${expires}; path=/; secure; samesite=lax`
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, I fixed the `window.onload` statement by saving the function to a variable `windowInit`, then calling it in `window.onload`.

```
const windowInit = () => {
    if (checkCookie(cookieName) != cookieState) {
        displayBanner();
    }
}

window.onload = windowInit();
```